# How to define route for login form on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have created a simple demo project in node js with Express 4.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var login = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/login', login);



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

**routes/login.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require("pg");

var conString = //connction string

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("in get");
    res.render('login');   
});

router.post('/Submit', function (req, res) {
    console.log("In post");
    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    try {
        client.connect();
    }
                catch (err) {
        console.log("Error:", err);
    }
    if (req.body) {
        var query = client.query("INSERT INTO DemoT(Email,Password) values($1,$2,$3)", [req.body.value[0], req.body.value[1]]);
        query.on("end", function (result) {
            client.end();
        });
    }

    return res.redirect('/login');

});

module.exports = router;
```

**public\javascripts\SubmitForms.js**

```
$(function () {
    $("#BtnSubmit").click(function () {
        var value = new Array();
        var val1 = $('#email').val();
        var val2 = $('#pwd').val();
        value.push(val1, val2);

        var jsonData = { "value" : value }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Submit",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsonData,
            success: function (data, status, jq) { },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOption, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        })

    });
});
```

I have debug the app, SubmitForm.js is call when the submit button click.When I click on the submit button, the control goes on `router.get`

Comment: Check in console for XHR details connection if it's really POST. `$.ajax` does weirdly sometimes.

Comment: though you can do as you want, as per my knowledge it's not recommendable to create a new route file for each route. In fact, you can write several routes right there in your `routes/index.js` file. Then, you can access your login page as `domain.com/login`.

Answer (score 1):

You mount `login` router to `/login` path. So you must submit to `/login/Submit`:

```
    var jsonData = { "value" : value }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/login/Submit",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsonData,
        success: function (data, status, jq) { },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOption, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    })
```